processing live metric data using opentelemetry dotnet
I would like to save realtime data using opentelemetry. But now it exports my data at a set interval, witch means that if my data changes in between intervals it gets lost. Right now i use the OtlpExporter that exports my data to a docker image opentelemetry-collector and that exports the data to influxdb.
Is there some way of exporting the data at a given point?
Right now the following is my configruation:
telBuilder.WithMetrics(metrics => metrics
   .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
   .AddMeter("HandshakeMeter")
   .AddOtlpExporter(config =>
   {
      config.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:4317");
      config.BatchExportProcessorOptions.ScheduledDelayMilliseconds = 100;
   })
);

I also have the feeling I am doing something wrong with the meter.CreateObservableGauge($"HandShake_{StationName}", () => Measurements(args));
because every time I make a measurement I call the CreateObservableGauge();
public class StationMetrics
{
    private readonly Meter _meter;
    private readonly IStation _station;
    private readonly Counter<int> _enterPositionCounter;
    private readonly IDataAccessStrategy<IStation> _stationDataAccess;
    private static readonly Meter meter = new Meter("HandshakeMeter", "1.0.0");
    private ObservableGauge<int> _observableGauge;
    private Thread _thread;

    public StationMetrics(IDataAccess dataAccess)
    {
        _stationDataAccess = dataAccess.GetDataAccess<IStation>();
        _thread = new Thread(StartThread);
        _thread.IsBackground = true;
        _thread.Start();
        _stationDataAccess = dataAccess.GetDataAccess<IStation>();
        
    }

    private void StartThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var stations = _stationDataAccess.GetAll();

            foreach (var station in stations)
            {
                UpdateStationOpenTelemetry(station.Name, station.HandshakeRequest);
                
            }

            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
    
    private void UpdateStationOpenTelemetry(string StationName, HandshakeRequestArgs args)
    {
        _observableGauge = meter.CreateObservableGauge($"HandShake_{StationName}", () => Measurements(args));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Measurement<int>> Measurements(HandshakeRequestArgs args)
    {
        return new List<Measurement<int>>
        {
            new (args.ActionDone ? 1 : 0, new KeyValuePair<string, object>[]
            {
                new ("Action", "ActionDone"),
            }),
            new (args.AtPosition ? 1 : 0, new KeyValuePair<string, object>[]
            {
                new ("Action","AtPosition"),
            }),
            new (args.EnterPosition ? 1 : 0, new KeyValuePair<string, object>[]
            {
                new ("Action", "EnterPosition"),
            }),
            new (args.LeavedPosition ? 1 : 0, new KeyValuePair<string, object>[]
            {
                new ("Action", "LeavedPosition"),
            })
        };
    }

    public static void ManualMeasurement(string stationName, HandshakeRequestArgs args)
    {
        meter.CreateObservableGauge($"HandShake_{stationName}", () => Measurements(args));
    }
}


This is a bit of a misunderstanding of Metrics and their usecase. Metrics are, by definition, an aggregation over time, and not singular. For Singular items like that, use Traces or even logs, then aggregate in the backend. The different telemetry signals have different usecases.
